# Swift - inheritance generic of generic with constraint

Tags: swift, generics, mvvm

I am trying to use Mvvm in app. 
For example I created few classes:

```
class ViewModel { }

class PaginationViewModel<TElement> : ViewModel { }

class UsersViewModel : PaginationViewModel<Int> {
    func didLoad() { }
}

class MvvmViewController<TViewModel : ViewModel> : UIViewController { }

class PaginationViewController<TPaginationViewModel> : MvvmViewController<TPaginationViewModel>
    where TPaginationViewModel: PaginationViewModel<Any> { }

class UsersViewController : PaginationViewController<UsersViewModel> {

}
```

I got following error - 'PaginationViewController' requires that 'UsersViewModel' inherit from 'PaginationViewModel'

How can I change generic constraint on PaginationViewController to make this code works?

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to achieve (the actual problem you are trying to solve)? Swift generics are invariant, so `PaginationViewModel<Int>` and `PaginationViewModel<Any>` are completely unrelated types, that is why your code doesn't compile.

Comment: @Dávid Pásztor, I want to make UsersViewController derrived from PaginationViewController<UsersViewModel>, but I need specify TElement in PaginationViewModel. In this example I set it to Any trying to make thing right. So how can I correctly define PaginationViewController<TPaginationViewModel> where TViewModel = PaginationViewModel?

Comment: I just realize that is not possible. I have to declare T in PaginationViewController to satisfy generic. Just like that: class PaginationViewController<TPaginationViewModel, T> : MvvmViewController<TPaginationViewModel>
    where TPaginationViewModel: PaginationViewModel<T> { }